# A right adjoint to the truncated Witt functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

For any ring $A$, let $\mathrm{wEt}_A$ be the category of weakly etale $A$-algebras ; it is a cocomplete category. By a theorem of Van der Kallen, the truncated Witt vector functor 
$$
W_r : \mathrm{wEt}_A \longrightarrow \mathrm{wEt}_{W_r(A)}
$$
is well-defined and commutes with all colimits.

> Can one explicit a right adjoint to $W_r$ ?

Comment: Greenberg functor?

Comment: Can you give a reference, or expand your answer ?